# ERROR - Sonar is unable to analyze file

Tags: sonarqube

I got this error while analyzing a CSharp project with sonar. The build was successfull.. But these errors are not looks good. What is the reason for this errors.

```
[WARN] [02:29:08.248] Unknown char: "»" (FisrtFile.cs:1:2)
[WARN] [02:29:08.248] Unknown char: "¿" (FisrtFile.cs:1:3)
[ERROR] [02:29:08.286] Sonar is unable to analyze file : 'F:\jenkins\workspace\sonar-ProjectA-1\ProjectA\ProjectA\DSService\FisrtFile.cs'
com.sonar.sslr.A.E: ------
-->   ï»¿using System;
    2 using System.Collections.Generic;
    3 using System.Linq;
    4 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    5 using System.Text;
    7 namespace
------
Expected : <EXTERN type> but was : <ï [IDENTIFIER]> ('FisrtFile.cs': Line 1 / Column 0)
  at externAliasDirective := EXTERN alias IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON

    at com.sonar.sslr.A.F.B(Unknown Source) ~[sonar-csharp-squid-plugin-1.0.jar:na]
    at com.sonar.sslr.A.F.A(Unknown Source) ~[sonar-csharp-squid-plugin-1.0.jar:na]
    at com.sonar.csharp.squid.scanner.CSharpAstScanner.A(Unknown Source) [sonar-csharp-squid-plugin-1.0.jar:na]
    at com.sonar.csharp.squid.scanner.CSharpAstScanner.scanFiles(Unknown Source) [sonar-csharp-squid-plugin-1.0.jar:na]
    at com.sonar.plugins.csharp.squid.C.analyse(Unknown Source) [sonar-csharp-squid-plugin-1.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:101) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanContainer.doStart(ScanContainer.java:147) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:72) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:65) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scanRecursively(ScanTask.java:56) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scanRecursively(ScanTask.java:54) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:49) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doStart(TaskContainer.java:188) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:72) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskBootstrapContainer.executeTask(TaskBootstrapContainer.java:73) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskBootstrapContainer.doStart(TaskBootstrapContainer.java:62) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:72) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doStart(BootstrapContainer.java:104) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:72) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:88) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:72) [sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:150) [sonar-maven-plugin-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490) [maven-2.2.1-uber.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:98) [sonar-maven-plugin-1.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:79) [sonar-maven-plugin-1.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:88) [sonar-maven-plugin-1.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490) [maven-2.2.1-uber.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694) [maven-2.2.1-uber.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569) [maven-2.2.1-uber.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539) [maven-2.2.1-uber.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387) [maven-2.2.1-uber.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284) [maven-2.2.1-uber.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180) [maven-2.2.1-uber.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328) [maven-2.2.1-uber.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138) [maven-2.2.1-uber.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362) [maven-2.2.1-uber.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60) [maven-2.2.1-uber.jar:2.2.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_21-ea]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_21-ea]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_21-ea]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_21-ea]
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315) [classworlds-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255) [classworlds-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430) [classworlds-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375) [classworlds-1.1.jar:1.1]
```

I sonar GUI, In component view I can see this file. But it does not have any metric values. No lines, lines of code, covegare, Rules Compliance etc.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: There is obviously a wrong character at the beginning of your file. "ï»¿using System;"

Comment: Nope. There is no such characters at the beginning of file. As **Fabrice** said the problem is with `SourceEncoding`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the correct encoding for your source files, using the ["sonar.sourceEncoding" property](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters).

For instance, in your case, put this in your sonar-project.properties file:

```
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer **Fabrice**. But this is error is not coming when I using the latest C# plugins(2.1). The error is coming with C# Ecosystem 1.3. Is `SourceEnocding` is set to UTF-8 by default in 2.1?